# How to send TLS client certificates from a React Native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, ssl, expo

I have a React Native application deployed on devices, and they need to communicate with an endpoint requiring TLS mutual authentication: I need to send a TLS client certificate along with the request.

It works well when in Node (API to API) using [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) for instance.

Reusing the same code in React Native didn't work, so I tried a couple other methods / libraries:

- The official `fetch` API does not allow to send client certificates
- axios requires `https` which is not available either

I came to realize that maybe React Native does not provide a way of doing it "natively" without using a native module (?), since it would mean importing a TLS implementation in pure JS (inefficient and slow I guess?).

What is the best way to perform mutual TLS authentication from a React Native application?

Comment: Were you able to get this going with React Native or did you have to go the Native Module way?